# How can I make yii2-export work in a modal window?

Tags: php, modal-dialog, yii-extensions, yii2

I'm having trouble using the very nice looking kartik-v/yii2-export module in a modal window.

Within the modal I have a Gridview widget, followed by:

```
echo ExportMenu::widget([
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    'columns' => $gridColumns
]);
```

This makes the export dropdown menu appear - but when I select any of the export options, nothing happens at all, with no errors.

If anyone could point me in the right direction, it would be hugely appreciated.

Comment: Did you solved this? i have a similar problem.